# Best soil decision for planting succulent seeds

Tags: soil, succulents, planting

Guys could you please suggest any soil or soils mixture for planting succulent seeds?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is (in my humble opinion) too generic. Could you describe better what kind of succulent you are interested. Succulent is very generic, there are some for dry places (acid or basic, sand or just compact soil), some for cold places, etc.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi some of the succulent are: Mesembryanthemum species, Argyroderma, Lithops, Carpobrotus, Cheiridopsis, Crassula, Gibbaeum, Lithops, Faucaria, Fenestraria